# Can I say "The results may change according to how much time you spend in the quiz"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am designing an English test for my students. However, I'm not a native speaker.

I want to design a quiz that can judge a student's result not only by his/her answers, but also by how much time he/she spent in that quiz.

What's the best way to express this?

Can I say

> The result(s) may change according to how much time you spend in the quiz

(BTW, should we say "result" or "results" for a quiz?)

Comment: Why might the results change? It seems like an odd thing to say in the first place. If I heard that, I'd immediately ask for clarification. Or is there context that is missing? Do you get a higher mark for taking less time—or are you saying that spending more time to consider your answers could help you?

Answer (score 1):

You could say something like this:

> **Your results** may change according to **the amount of time** you spend **on**
>   the quiz.

Using the plural form (results) as you are referencing to multiple students.

Comment: So ... `your result` and `the results`? May I know why? Thanks!

Comment: edited the answer so it is more clear. also wait for natives to answer as I am not a native speaker :)